# How to display last 12 months of data in proper order in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I want the count of last 12 months records group by MM-YYYY.

```
select to_char((SCHEDULED_START_DT), 'MM-YYYY') , count(*)
    from XYZ where  SCHEDULED_START_DT > TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -11), 'MM')
    group by to_char((SCHEDULED_START_DT), 'MM-YYYY')
```

This is the output of the above query.

[image]

But i want the output to be in the following order

```
10-2016
11-2016
12-2016
01-2017
02-2017
03-2017
04-2017
05-2017
06-2017
07-2017
08-2017
09-2017
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: The easiest way is to display yyyy-mm instead of mm-yyyy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is to order by any one date from each period.  The `min()` or `max()` will do for ordering purposes:

```
select to_char(SCHEDULED_START_DT, 'MM-YYYY'), count(*)
from XYZ
where SCHEDULED_START_DT > TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -11), 'MM')
group by to_char(SCHEDULED_START_DT, 'MM-YYYY') 
order by min(SCHEDULED_START_DT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to group by a date (rather than a string) and then sort by it:

```
select to_char(trunc(SCHEDULED_START_DT,'MM'), 'MM-YYYY') , count(*)
from XYZ where SCHEDULED_START_DT > TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -11), 'MM')
group by trunc(SCHEDULED_START_DT,'MM')
order by trunc(SCHEDULED_START_DT,'MM')
```

Answer (score -1):

select to_char(SCHEDULED_START_DT, 'MM-YYYY'), count(*)
from XYZ
where SCHEDULED_START_DT > TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -11), 'MM')
group by to_char(SCHEDULED_START_DT, 'MM-YYYY') 
order by SCHEDULED_START_DT DESC;

Should do it!